# KendoUI Grid button in column

Tags: kendo-grid

I have a KendoUI Grid in my MVC.

[image]

And here's the code for it.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TekstenViewModel.Tekst>()
      .Name("Grid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(product => product.Naam).Width(100);
          columns.Bound(product => product.Waarde).Width(100);
          columns.Bound(product => product.Opmerking).Width(250);
          columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<a class=\"delete iconBtn\" onclick=\"onClickDeleteResourceItem(#: ID #, '#: Naam #')\"></a>").Title("").Width(50);

      })
          .ToolBar(toolbar =>
          {
              toolbar.Create();
              toolbar.Save();
          })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .Groupable()
    .Navigatable()
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(true)
        .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(product => product.ID);
                model.Field(product => product.RESOURCE_SET_ID).DefaultValue(Model.SetID);
                model.Field(product => product.Type).DefaultValue(Domain.Agromilieu2.Common.Objects.Entities.Resources.ResourceType.GLOBAL_RESOURCES);
                model.Field(product => product.Taal).DefaultValue(Domain.Agromilieu2.Common.Agromilieu2Constants.Resources.DEFAULT_TAAL_CODE);
            })
            .Create(create => create.Action(MVC.BeheerTeksten.ActionNames.ResourceItems_CreateUpdate, MVC.BeheerTeksten.Name))
            .Read(read => read.Action(MVC.BeheerTeksten.ActionNames.ResourceItems_Read, MVC.BeheerTeksten.Name, new { setID = Model.SetID }))
            .Update(update => update.Action(MVC.BeheerTeksten.ActionNames.ResourceItems_CreateUpdate, MVC.BeheerTeksten.Name))
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action(MVC.BeheerTeksten.ActionNames.ResourceItems_Delete, MVC.BeheerTeksten.Name))
    )
    )
```

Now I need to change it into this.

[image]

And without success so far. Everytime I try to put text and a button in a column, the text disappears. Any ideas??

Comment: sorry i am not understand your question exctly can you explain mode?

Comment: I think it explains itself. I need to put a button together with text in the same column.